# VBA Set named columns to zero

Tags: excel, vba

In my worksheet "gar_nv", I have a list of columns that I named "GCPCC0", "GCPCC1" and "GCPCC2. I would like to set them to zero starting the 2nd cell.

```
Sub CstVal()

Call Workbook_open

Dim Name As Variant
Dim i As Long

With gar_nv
    nbr_lines = .UsedRange.Rows.Count
    List = Array("GCCP0", "GCPCC1", "GCPCC2")
    For Each Name In List
        For i = 1 To nbr_lines
            .Range(Name).Rows(i).Value = "0"
            
        Next i
    Next
    
    
End With
End Sub
```

This line throws a 1004 error, how can I fix it ?

```
.Range(Name).Rows(i).Value = "0"
```

Comment: Cells have values. Not rows.

Comment: Please could you check out the answers to your recent questions?

Answer (score 1):

### Fill Column Data Ranges (the Range Below the Headers)

```
Option Explicit

Sub CstVal()

    'Call Workbook_open ' irrelevant
    
    With gar_nv
        
        Dim nmList As Variant: nmList = Array("GCCP0", "GCPCC1", "GCPCC2")
        
        Dim nm As Variant
        
        For Each nm In nmList
            With .Range(nm)
                'Debug.Print .Address, .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1).Address
                .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1).Value = 0
            End With
        Next nm
    
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: This should work but it throws a 1004 error at the : With .Range(nm)

Comment: Possibly you need to make sure the names are of **worksheet** (not of workbook) scope.

Comment: they are, I checked

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

1st option:

```
.Range(Name & i).Value = "0"
```

OR

2nd option:

```
.Cells(i,Name).Value = "0"
```

Hope it works.